# Send notification by position when app is closed

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, notifications, gps

I'm programming with unity, so i don't know much about Android and iOS but what I need is something that sends a notification to the user when he/she reaches a location,

so like if the users gets close to a point defined by GPS coords I'll send a notification.

That's is quite simple when the app is ON or in background, but what if the app is completely close? How do I do that? Like how does google maps know where I'm at while I don't have Google Maps opened or in background? How does whatsapp send message notification when I close the app by swiping it up?

Any hint? I know whatsapp and so on use a sort of "keepalive" process separated from the actual main app, but what does it do? How do I set a process to work like that?

By searching I managed to find out I can use a "service" fro android, ok. What about iOS?

Comment: This unanswered question on unity's forum might help: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/605562/can-unity-run-in-the-background-on-mobile-for-trac.html